# Building custom filter method in Rails/SQL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create a filter for an Article class that uses a SQL query built on the fly based on the parameters submitted from an HTML form. Since I have multiple many-to-many relationships, I can't use Article.where ( I don't think anyways ). While the following code works, I am unsure as to whether this is the most effective way to execute this query and just how secure it is. I do make a point to guard against SQL injection by using the ? keyword in the sql string ( a la Rails convention), but wanted to make sure that would be enough. Any advice on how I can make this more elegant?

```
def self.filter(hash)
    hash.delete_if {|k,v| v == ""}
    hash[:writer_type] = (hash[:writer_type]) if hash[:writer_type] != nil
    sql_base = "select distinct articles.* from articles
       join tags
       on tags.article_id = articles.id
       join categories
       on tags.category_id = categories.id
       left outer join itineraries
       on itineraries.article_id = articles.id
       left outer join cities
       on itineraries.city_id = cities.id
       join users
       on users.id = articles.user_id"

    condition_array = []
    key_array = []
    hash.each_key {|key| key_array << key}
    key_array.each_with_index do |key, i|
      operator = "and"
      operator = "where" if i == 0
      case key
      when :writer
        sql_base << "\n#{operator} users.username like ?"
        condition_array << hash[:writer]
      when :writer_type
         sql_base << "\n#{operator} users.status in (?)"
        condition_array << hash[:writer_type]
      when :city
        sql_base << "\n#{operator} cities.name like ?" 
        condition_array << hash[:city]
      when :category
        sql_base << "\n#{operator} categories.name like ?"
        condition_array << hash[:category]
      end
    end
    sql_array = [sql_base,condition_array].flatten
    articles = Article.find_by_sql(sql_array)
    articles
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you should be able to do something like this:

```
q = Articles.join(:tags #, etc)

if condition
  q = q.joins(:user).where("users.status in ?", hash[:writer_type])
else
  q = q.joins(:cities).where("cities.name LIKE ?", hash[:city])
end

q
```

This works because `ActiveRecord::Relation` only executes the query on first access. So until you call `to_a` or enumerate through the records you can continue to chain onto the object.

If you are doing complicated queries you might want to look at [squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel) It would let you rewrite your conditions like

```
q.where { users.status >> my { hash[:writer_type] } }
```

or

```
q.where { cities.name =~ my { hash[:city] } }
```